# What would be ideal & cost effective solution/selection between AWS EC2 or Lambda for below scenario in long term

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

First of all, I hope everyone is safe and healthy in this difficult Covid 19 situation.

Q: What would be ideal & cost effective solution/selection between AWS EC2  or Lambda for below scenario in long term:

Suppose, I have to host a backend (Python based Flask) which contains at most 40 API endpoints which will be used by both react based web app & react native based mobile app.

Out of those 40 , Only 5 api's will be having average  concurrency of max 500 and total API hits could be around ~1500 to ~2000  daily average for all 40 API's.

Idle time could be 8 to 10 hr daily

Comment: How complex are these API endpoints? What are the skill levels of the people maintaining these?

Comment: Do you have an RDBMS in this solution? Do you have experience with Flask on Lambda?